# Куда девался WritePrivateProfileInt?..

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Для загрузки параметров из ini файла я использую функцию GetPrivateProfileInt, логично, для сохранения параметров нужно пользоваться WritePrivateProfileInt. Но в VS2012 его нет! Есть аналоги?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Есть аналоги?

Не знаю насчет `VS2012`, `GetPrivateProfileString` - это все же функция `WinAPI`, а не `Visual Studio` но аналог можно сделать так:

```
char Buffer[100];
sprintf( Buffer, "%i", MyIntValue );
::WritePrivateProfileStringA( ..., Buffer, ... );
```

или так:

```
char Buffer[100];
::WritePrivateProfileStringA( ..., _itoa( MyIntValue, Buffer, 10 ), ... );
```

т.е., такую запись `Int` можно считать впоследствие через `GetPrivateProfileInt`, ошибок не будет.

Comment: Ясно, у меня была такая идея, но хотелось бы без танцев с бубнами. Спасибо.

Comment: >без танцев с бубнами

>Minimum supported client Windows 2000 Professional [desktop apps only]

Должна быть. Поищите в WinBase.h

Answer (score 2):

Вообще уроды из Microsoft говорят, что эти функции (для работы с конфигурационными файлами) устарели и программа должна хранить все параметры конфигурации в реестре. Но мы то понимаем, что это плохо и конфигурационные файлы это круто.

1. [**GetPrivateProfileInt**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724345.aspx)
2. [**WritePrivateProfileString**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms725501.aspx)

> Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications. Applications should store initialization information in the registry.

Поэтому решением может быть как отказ от ф-ций Win32API в пользу специализированных компонентов, так и вызов ф-ции напрямую. По поводу первого - посмотрите, например, класс [QSetting](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsettings.html) из библиотеки Qt. Если будете его использовать, то и под линуксом он будет работать точно так же, как и под виндой. Если второе - если ф-ция все-таки все еще есть в разделяемых библиотеках, то Вас спасет комбинация `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress`

Еще вариант - сделать собственную функцию. Например, предлагают такой вариант кода

```
BOOL WritePrivateProfileInt (LPCTSTR lpAppName, LPCTSTR lpKeyName, int Value, LPCTSTR lpFileName)
{
  char  Buffer[16];

  sprintf (Buffer,"%d",Value);
  return WritePrivateProfileString(lpAppName,lpKeyName,Buffer,lpFileName);  
}
```

**Не забывайте про использование правильных строковых типов!!!** В данном примере кода есть небольшая проблема, но ее устранить можно без особых сложностей.

Comment: Только WritePrivateProfileString замените на WritePrivateProfileStringA, иначе в UNICOD'е будут проблемы.

Comment: Касательно WritePrivateProfileInt - это не мой код, а стыренный с интернета. Поэтому я и написал, что "предлагают"

> Не забывать про них нужно Вам, т.к. Вы используете char, а не кто-либо еще.

Ага. А еще лучше - переписать под TCHAR :-), чтоб был универсальный вариант.

Comment: >Касательно WritePrivateProfileInt - это не мой код, а стыренный с интернета. 

А, понятно, не очень заметно, если честно.

>А еще лучше - переписать под TCHAR :-), чтоб был универсальный вариант

Можно, конечно. Я тоже сначала так подумал, но для перевода `int'а` - ИМХО, избыточно.