# Есть ли аналоги GetPrivateProfileIntA, но под тип float или double?

Tags: winapi

Есть ли аналоги GetPrivateProfileIntA, но для типа float или double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что нет. Варианты решения: либо парсить ini-файл вручную, либо использовать сторонние библиотеки для работы с ini, либо (если программа ваша) сохранять и загружать значения float в виде строк (функциями `WritePrivateProfileString` и `GetPrivateProfileString`). Еще вариант (опять же, если программа ваша) - воспользоваться советом из MSDN и хранить настройки в реестре.

**Дополнение.** Можно посмотреть в сторону других форматов для хранения настроек, например, json или yaml. Некоторые программы вообще хранят настройки в скриптах Lua (не знаю, насколько это безопасно, поэтому не советую).

xml не советую, потому что слишком многословный и не особенно легко читаемый, если все-таки предполагается ручное редактирование.

WinAPI для работы с этими форматами нет, но полно разных сторонних библиотек.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - типы данных для реестра. Нет ничего для дробных чисел...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, dword, qword, binary, sz - в любом из них можно хранить дробные числа.

Comment: Строка и atof, IMHO, самый годный вариант. Остается читаемость и возможно редактирования руками.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в реестре не нужна читаемость, а вот более высокая плотность записи и отсутствие потери точности при перезаписи при хранении в двоичном виде - это несомненный плюс.

Comment: @insolor Ну топикастер, видимо, просто не сталкивался с пользователями. И думает, что кто-то будет лезть в файл настроек и что-то там делать. Ни один нормальный юзер такой фигней не страдает. Он просто забъет болт на такую программу. Если продукт топикастера заставляет пользователя редактировать ручками файлы настроек, то, на мой взгляд, это абсолютно не годный продукт. А с учетом использования функций не по назначению - и подавно не годный продукт. Переубеждать таких людей не имеет смысла. Все приходит с опытом.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте другие функции. Данная была предусмотрена только для совместимости с 16-разрядными приложениями на базе Windows.

Comment: Что именно для работы с INI вы можете предложить под эту задачу?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Я не знаю Вашей задачи. Но можно использовать реестр, как упомянуто в другом ответе. Но если необходимо локально сохранять настройки, то можно их не в ini-файле хранить, а, например, в xml. Возьмите простую библиотеку [tinyxml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyXML) и работайте с xml. Но, заострю внимание на том, что в своем ответе я хотел скорее предупредить о том, чтобы Вы не использовали именно **GetPrivateProfileIntA**. Ведь не ровен час и просто-напросто данная функция может "внезапно" оказаться неподдерживаемой в новой версии ОС.

Comment: А типы данных в реестре вы видели? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - что там для дробных чисел есть? В первую очередь вы советуете использовать "другие функции", которых, тащемта, и нет. Особенно для работы с INI-файлами.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, float можно хранить в dword, а double в qword или binary. Ну или в строковом виде (sz), например.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Я знаком с типами данных в реестре. Ничто не мешает, как было сказано в другом ответе, использовать для хранения строки. И повторюсь: Возможно, что я не ясно выразился в ответе, а затем Вы не поняли меня в комментарии, но я рекомендую отказаться от этой функции, и не заставляю Вас работать с реестром или другими библиотеками. Причину я Вам указал.

Answer (score 0):

> либо (если программа ваша) сохранять и загружать значения float в виде строк (функциями WritePrivateProfileString и GetPrivateProfileString)

Поддержу это мнение, т.к. `Get/WritePrivateProfileIntA` делает примерно [то же самое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/178374/8766). Для `double`, например это можно сделать так:

```
TCHAR buffer[100];
double value = 0;

::GetPrivateProfileString(..., buffer, _countof(buffer), ...);
if(_stscanf(buffer, TEXT("%lf"), &value) == 1){
  // use value...
}
```